# Stop Xcode debugger from stepping through auto generated and code you have not written

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

When I use the debugger in Xcode I often only want to use it to step through the classes and code I have written only. Not the auto generated assembly code or code in libraries I'm using.

Is there an easy way to do this? I can't find anything browsing through the options. The only threads I could find on this subject didn't help.

[Keep xcode debugger from stepping out of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835021/keep-xcode-debugger-from-stepping-out-of-file)

Comment: If there's no way to do this I guess I'll just have to stick to Stepping Out.

Comment: Use the step over arrow when you want to step over a line of code and the step in button when you want to step into something.. step over third party code that you don't care about but step into your own code